# JQuery shortcut for callbacks like function(){ mycallback() }

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hi javascript developers,

Is there a way to reduce the boilerplate required to define a function in jquery?

(My example is with a callback but it could apply to any anon function.)

`$('#dialog').load('/index.cgi',{p:'myform'}, function(){ ajaxify_form() });`

What I would like is to do

`$('#dialog').load('/index.cgi',{p:'myform'}, $.f(){ ajaxify_form() });`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boilerplate you have isn't required. Just pass in the function directly:

```
$('#dialog').load('/index.cgi',{p:'myform'}, ajaxify_form);
```

is for all intents and purposes equivalent to:

```
$('#dialog').load('/index.cgi',{p:'myform'}, function() { ajaxify_form(); });
```

*except that the meaning of* `this` *will differ within the function*.

**Note:** don't do it this way:

```
$('#dialog').load('/index.cgi',{p:'myform'}, ajaxify_form());
```

as that does something completely different. Instead of passing in the function you pass in what the function returns.

Comment: The only difference is that the `this` keyword, inside the `ajaxify_form` function, in the first example will refer to the `#dialog` DOM element, in the second example, it will refer to the global object (`window`).